# Difference between Linux and Hurd, from an (advanced) user/programmer point-of-view

Tags: linux

I've seen that systems running on top of Hurd start to become available (namely [Arch Hurd](http://www.archhurd.org/)) and I was wondering how a user, anyhow advance s/he can be, can see a difference?

<del>Linux and BSD should be pretty much the same, because both of them are monolithic kernel, so the only difference should be their syscall API.</del>

NB: when I write Linux, I don't mean GNU/Linux, as I guess that the GNU environment should eventually be the same in both systems

**EDIT**: deleted the statement about BSD, I don't know anything about this system and that's not the point of my question :$

**EDIT 2**: Let's try another approach: I have a good knowledge of GNU/Linux. What would be different with GNU/Hurd? for instance,

- module certainly can't exist with a micro-kernel, what's the equivalent? how does a video card driver looks like ?
- if the Hurd kernel (Mach) delegates core-tasks to user-space processes, which are they?
- who is in charge of these core tasks ? (an equivalent of super-`init`?)

*(side-question: does this question belongs to stackoverflow?)*

Comment: @Ignacio but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel) lists xBSD among the monolithic kernel ... ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hurd** -> **Microkernel**

while

**Linux** -> **Monolithic kernel**

similar to the difference b/w monolithic kernel and Microkernel

**1** ) Monolithic kernel is much **older than Microkernel**. It’s used in Unix .
    **While** 
    Idea of microkernel appeared at the end of the **1980's**.

**2** ) the example of os having the Monolithic kernels are **UNIX , LINUX**
    **While** 
    the os having Microkernel are **QNX , L4 , HURD** , initially **Mach** (not mac os x) later it will              converted into hybrid kernel , even **MINIX** is not pure kernel because device driver are compiled as part of the kernel .

**3** ) Monolithic kernel are **faster than microkernel** .
  **While** 
 The first microkernel  Mach is 50% slower than Monolithic kernel while later version like **L4 only 2% or 4% slower** than the Monolithic kernel .

**4** ) Monolithic kernel generally are **bulky** .
**While** 
    Pure monolithic kernel has to be **small in size** even fit in s into processor first level cache (first generation microkernel).

**5**) in the Monolithic kernel device driver **reside in the kernel space** .
**While** 
  In the Microkernel device driver **reside in the user space**.

**6** ) since the device driver reside in the kernel space it make monolithic kernel **less secure** than microkernel . (Failure in the driver may lead to crash)
**While** 
    Microkernels are **more secure** than the monolithic kernel hence used in some military devices.

**7** ) Monolithic kernels use signals and sockets to ensure IPC 
while 
    microkernel approach uses message queues . 1 gen of microkernel poorly implemented IPC so were slow on context switches.

**8** ) adding new feature to a monolithic system means **recompiling the whole kernel** 
While 
   You can add new feature or patches **without recompiling**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not first read up on what HURD is: http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/what_is_the_gnu_hurd.html

In short (from my understanding) HURD is a kernel running on top of a MACH micro kernel allowing for updates of even the HURD kernel stuff without a reboot.

That is all nice and theoretic, but in practice the only thing you'll notice is the lack of (driver) support for HURD.

HURD is like BSD and LINUX . . all pretty much the same but different. They are all kernels with their own pros and cons.

Comment: "all pretty much the same but different" I can't believe it :) I _has_ to be different in a way, at some level!

Comment: The microkernel design and some philosophy, it seems.